# How do I know if a group of async functions have completed executing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

My news website serves 3 types of content: articles, videos and tweets. I load **one** or **all** of these content types based on a received parameter. So:

```
switch(param){
    case 'articles': loadArticles(); break;
    case 'videos': loadVideos(); break;
    case 'tweets': loadTweets(); break;
    default: loadArticles(); loadVideos(); loadTweets(); break;
}
```

I am using [NProgress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/) to give the user the illusion of progress. How do I set progress values in loadArticles(), loadVideos() and loadTweets() to mimic progress?

EDIT: Each of these functions have their respective factory calls (each of which have their own `$http.get()`). E.g.: `articleFactory.getArticles().then(function(data){$scope.articles = data;})`

Comment: To check if all of them are done, you can use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Comment: And to check their progress deferred `notify` comes to help.

Answer (score 1):

How about pass a reference of the progress as parameter to these functions, so they can update it?

```
case 'articles': loadArticles(progress); break;

function loadArticles(progress) {
    ...
    progress.add(0.15); //Or whatever you do to increment
}
```

Is this an alternative for you?

Comment: I thought of this. But I need to call NProgress.done() somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Turn each of those calls into a promise that you can defer, then use `$q.all()` to wait for them all to be done. Here's a pretty simple example of it in action, you'll have to adapt your code a little bit.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$q',
  function($scope, $timeout, $q) {
    var thenFn = function(value) {
        console.log('resolved ', value);
        return value;
      },
      q1 = $scope.q1 = $q.defer(),
      q2 = $scope.q2 = $q.defer(),
      p1 = $scope.q1.promise,
      p2 = $scope.q2.promise;

    //NProgress.start();
    $scope.testValue = $q.all([
        p1.then(thenFn),
        p2.then(thenFn)
      ])
      .then(function(values) {
        console.log('all promises resolved', values);
        //NProgress.complete();
      });

    $timeout(function() {
      console.log('resolving delayed promise 1');
      q1.resolve(1);      
    }, 1000);
    
    $timeout(function() {
      console.log('resolving delayed promise 2');
      q2.resolve(2);
    }, 2000);
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit** Bring up your dev tools to see the results when you run the code snippet.

**Second Edit** Also, there's an angular version of NProgress, ngProgress, [source](http://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(param){
    case 'articles':NProgress.start(); loadArticles();  NProgress.done() ; break;
    case 'videos': NProgress.start(); loadVideos();  NProgress.done() ; break;
    case 'tweets':NProgress.start(); loadTweets(); NProgress.done() ;  break;
    default: NProgress.start(); loadArticles(); loadVideos(); loadTweets();  NProgress.done() ;break;
}
```

you have to use  NProgress.set(somevalue) inside  loadArticles() loadVideos() and loadTweets()

Comment: You probably assumed there is no async call in the load functions. My bad; edited the question.